# nice way to make a pyramid with numbers >10

Tags: c

I'm new to C and programming in general. I wanted to create a pyramid of numbers I have seen on a class test. I managed to do it, but the problem is that when the numbers get over 9, the pyramid gets terrific. [this is what I wanted to achieve without writing a lot of IFs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/impzx.jpg)

my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int strlen(char *str);

int main(int argc, char **args){
char spaces[] = {"|                              "};
int i = 1, line = 1; //line number of numbers per line

while(spaces[strlen(spaces)-1] != '|'){

    printf("%s", spaces);
    
    for(int k = 0; k < line; k++){
        printf("%d", i);
        i++;
    }

    printf("\n");
    
    spaces[strlen(spaces)-1] = '\0';        
    
    line += 2;
}
}

int strlen(char *str){
int i = 0;

while(*(str + i))
    i++;

return i;
}
```

Comment: If the numbers in the pyramid are > 9 then you obviously need to output at least one space between them. You don't need any array: just output consecutive formatted values with a newline where  needed.

Comment: I would recommend you just use strlen() from string.h and not try to define it yourself. Also you need to know the maximum depth your pyramid will be and then use that to determine how many spaces will be printed on the top levels

Comment: yes I was going to add the spaces but the thing doesn't change, I wanted a clean pyramid and not something that grow longer and longer, I can fix it with many IFs but I think there is a better way.
I wanted to create the function myself because our professor wants us to learn better C

Comment: I don't understand the problem then. If you want a pyramid with 100 lines, how can you avoid a base 100 units long? As mentioned, you don't need any array. Just print the values.

Comment: ... and after 1 value you print a newline, and some leading spaces. Then after 2 values, then 3, 4 etc.

Comment: "I wanted a clean pyramid" Please show the one you would like to see. Create it manually, then people can help you with doing it by program. Use text instead of a picture of text please. Using the code formatting option should be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

You showed what you *wanted to achieve without writing a lot of IFs*: print the pyramid of numbers with a field width of 6. Your principal approach was right: in each line, first print the leading spaces, then print the numbers. What is missing is to account for the field width of the leading spaces as well as the numbers themselves. This can be done e. g. by changing your `while` loop to

```
    int lines = 16;     // how many lines you want
    while (lines--)
    {
        // in this line, we need leading spaces for `lines` numbers
        printf("%*s", lines*6, ""); // you chose 6 spaces per number
        // print each number with the chosen width
        for (int k = 0; k < line; k++) printf("%-6d", i++);
        puts("");
        line += 2;
    }
```